# Mounting directory in docker container and running Gradle command

Tags: git, gradle, docker

I have a docker container named `mydockimage` with gradle installed in it.

I am mounting my local work directory with following command

```
sudo docker run -t -a stdout -a stderr --rm \
  --volume /home/Myworkspace/Myproject:/workspace:rw myimage:myimage_build
```

I have the following issues:

1. after running this command from `/home`, I get redirected to the docker contanier `/workspace` folder but when i run **gradle** the response hangs.
2. if i run the mount script from my local workspace folder then its redirects me to docker container with all the files  but with the folder name and git branch 
   name in the flower bracket something like below

   ```
   [ root@c6ff3f80dab8:/workspace {COE *} ]$
   ```

   where COE is the branch name.
3. If I run `gradle build` in the `[ root@c6ff3f80dab8:/workspace {COE *} ]$` then application builds but returns back to my local directory and not sure how to find in my docker container.

Answer (score 1):

To find your docker container run command: `docker ps`. It will display running containers. `docker ps -a` will display **all** containers even closed ones.

Please provide your Dockerfile and command you build your image.